# Problems During Content Assistant in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

when I press Ctrl + Space in eclipse Juno it pops up following dialog box.

[image]

Anyone has an idea what's going n here ??

Comment: Did you try what the message says? "To avoid this message, disable the ..."?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Check whether multiple commands are registered for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> short cut.

Go to **Windows->Preferences** and in search box type **keys** and check. It should be shown as below.

[image]

If multiple commands are registered then change the other key bindings short cut other combination of keys.

Comment: It looks same as this